# Getting error Error "Entity 'J' not defined"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this line in app.config file:

```
<add key="MY_KEY" value="}N7+6}s&J*?C" />
```

However it is generating these errors:

[image]

The value `}N7+6}s&J*?C` is actually a password for something.

I also tried changing `&` to `&amp;` but in that case also I get the error:

```
Error   1   Application Configuration file "App.config" is invalid.
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 54, position 51.   
D:\DBF Export\matchDBF\App.config   54  51  matchDBF
```

Does anyone have an idea on how do I store that value in config file?

Comment: Well it _is_ XML so you would have to escape that `&`... That error is for something else... look at the part of the file that it's saying there's the error... line 54, position 51.

Comment: @JeffMercado: thanks btw should i use `&amp;` instead of `&` in that value right ? It should not affect my original password value ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must replace your `&` character by `&amp;`.